# Troubleshooting Issues with Qt Building

Tags: c++, qt, build, compilation, qt5

what does this error mean?

```
..\Qt\build-Baton-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\_deps\ds-build\src\imports\tools\eventsimulator\QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin_autogen\include\QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin_QtQuick_Studio_EventSimulatorPlugin.moc:174: error: opening dependency file _deps\ds-build\src\imports\tools\eventsimulator\CMakeFiles\QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin.dir\QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin_QtQuick_Studio_EventSimulatorPlugin.cpp.obj.d: No such file or directory

In file included from C:/Qt/6.5.3/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:34,
                 from C:/Qt/6.5.3/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:12,
                 from C:/Qt/6.5.3/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:12,
                 from C:/Qt/6.5.3/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:10,
                 from C:/Qt/6.5.3/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qplugin.h:12,
                 from C:/Qt/6.5.3/mingw_64/include/QtQml/qqmlextensionplugin.h:7,
                 from C:/Users/oliwi/OneDrive/Pulpit/Michal/Qt/build-Baton-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/_deps/ds-build/src/imports/tools/eventsimulator/QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin_QtQuick_Studio_EventSimulatorPlugin.cpp:3:

.../Qt/build-Baton-Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/_deps/ds-build/src/imports/tools/eventsimulator/QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin_autogen/include/QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin_QtQuick_Studio_EventSimulatorPlugin.moc:174:1: fatal error: opening dependency file _deps\ds-build\src\imports\tools\eventsimulator\CMakeFiles\QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin.dir\QuickStudioEventSimulatorplugin_QtQuick_Studio_EventSimulatorPlugin.cpp.obj.d: No such file or directory

  174 | QT_WARNING_POP
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am trying to build a Qt Quick app. The console app builds normally. I have already tried to change the compiler.

Comment: My guess is you need to get your files off of OneDrive based on others having issues compiling c++ code that were caused by having it on a OneDrive folder.

Comment: I think somehow maybe your Code looks for debug compiled source code but it is missing. Are you compiling in debug mode?